# Alternative Text in treeview control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, accessibility

I am looking for a solution. My treeview control contains the menuitems for my web application and its populated from a sitemap and it's working fine. Now I need to add alternative text to that menu items created. How can I add alternative text to these treeview items.

My treeview code is like below

```
protected void MainMenu_NodeDataBound(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    var siteMapnode = e.Node.DataItem as SiteMapNode;
    e.Node.Value = siteMapnode.Url;
    e.Node.NavigateUrl = string.Empty;
    e.Node.SelectAction = (siteMapnode.Url != String.Empty) ? TreeNodeSelectAction.Select : TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
    e.Node.PopulateOnDemand = false;         
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `e.Node.ToolTip` or `e.Node.Text`?

Comment: I mean alt in an anchor tag,once rendered treeview control is like anchor tags right? so i need to add alt text for treeview control

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you mean by 'alternative text' but you may be looking for the `Tag` property.

Example:

```
...

e.Node.Tag = "Alternative Text, whatever that means.";

...
```

You can set a `Node`'s `Tag` property to whatever you want since it's type `object`, which I find pretty handy. Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: i am using visual studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

There is no `alt`. I believe what you want is `title`, which is set using the `ToolTip` attribute:

```
e.Node.ToolTip = "I provide useful info about the link."
```

Which will get rendered as:

```
<a href="yourlink.aspx" title="I provide useful info about the link.">Some Text</a>
```

`alt` is used to specify alternate text for elements when they can't be rendered (i.e. NOT anchor tags). Outside of IE, browsers will *not* use this to provide text that displays when the element is hovered.

From [HTML Techniques for Web Content Accessibility Guidelines 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#links):

> In addition to clear link text, content developers may specify a value
>   of the "title" attribute that clearly and accurately describes the
>   target of the link.
>
> If more than one link on a page shares the same link text, all those
>   links should point to the same resource. Such consistency will help
>   page design as well as accessibility.
>
> If two or more links refer to different targets but share the same
>   link text, distinguish the links by specifying a different value for
>   the "title" attribute of each A element.

Comment: That also not help me ..what i need is something similar to alt in anchor tag..for completing accessibility issues there should be alt text

Comment: That is what `title` is for. Reading: [W3C Link Titles](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.1.4). [Alt attribute](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/altAttribute) is used primarily for images.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate text in ASP.Net :

```
AlternateText="Your Text"
```