# Add alt value to all the anchor tags inside a div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add alt value to all the anchor tags inside a particular div.
I need to loop through the div and find the anchor tag and add alt value.
structure is below like below

```
<div id="ctl00_MenuTreeView" style="font-size:11px;"     onadaptedselectednodechanged="OnNodeSelected">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<td class="TreeViewNode ctl00_MenuTreeView_2 ctl00_MenuTreeView_6"     onmouseout="TreeView_UnhoverNode(this)"     onmouseover="TreeView_HoverNode(ctl00_MenuTreeView_Data, this)">
<a id="ctl00_MenuTreeViewt0" class="ctl00_MenuTreeView_0 TreeViewNode     ctl00_MenuTreeView_1 ctl00_MenuTreeView_5" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;"     title="Home Page" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(ctl00_MenuTreeView_Data,     this,'ctl00_MenuTreeViewt0');"     href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MenuTreeView','s/wotc/Default.aspx')">Home</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0;">
</div>
```

thanks
alex

Comment: You don't need to do any looping. Where's the javascript that you've tried thus far?

Comment: how do i add alt to anchor tags inside all the table elements in a div,menu items are created dynamically from asp.net treeview control

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr

Comment: Are you adding the same alt tag to each, or are they different?

Comment: @user2217726 As I stated [in your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003874/alternative-text-in-treeview-control-in-asp-net), for accessibility on `a` tags, you use `title` not `alt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function OnTreeViewLoaded() {
  $('#ctl00_MenuTreeView .TreeViewNode a').attr('alt', 'whatever');
}
```